# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo 4

Tags: android

I get an error while using the corresponded code : 
how can i fix it ?

```
/**
 * Created by tal on 24/04/14.
 */
public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{
OurView v;
Bitmap ball;
float x,y;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v=new OurView(this);
    v=setOnTouchListener(this);
    ball= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
    x=y=0;
    setContentView(v);
}

private OurView setOnTouchListener(SurfaceViewExample surfaceViewExample) {
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v , MotionEvent me) {
    return false;
}

public class  OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread t=null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOK=false;

    public OurView(Context context){
        super(context);
        holder=getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       while (isItOK==true)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255,150,150,10);
            c.drawBitmap(ball,x,y,null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
    public void pause(){
        isItOK=false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t=null;

    }
    public void resume(){
        isItOK=true;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to start activity componentinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268861/unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo)

Answer (score 0):

Add listener after setcontentview

```
v = new OurView(this);
 setContentView(v);

 v.setOnTouchListener(this);
 ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
 x = y = 0;

Try this it will work
```

Comment: rate me by clicking up arrow on the post